# How to re create a section of my code with new variables through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a comment feature for my page so when a user comments some text, the comment will appear above the comment section as a new comment. I'm having issues with adding the new comment into the html from the javascript right now, what i want is the format of the comment of the new one same as my the first comment shown there, how can I go about this? Sorry if i'm unable to phrase my question properly :/

```js
var post= document.getElementById("post");
post.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('coment button pressed');

    var userComment=document.getElementById("comment-box").value;
    console.log(userComment)

    var text= document.createTextNode(userComment);
    console.log(text)

    var newComment = document.getElementById("new-comment");
    console.log(newComment)

    newComment.appendChild(userComment)
    


})
```

```css
  .comment-box,
  .post-comment .list{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
  }

.comment-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-comment .list{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.post-comment .list .user{
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-comment .list .user img{
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.comment-section .name{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-comment .list .day{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post-comment{
  padding: 0 0 15px 58px
}




#comment-box{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.comment-box .user{
  display: flex;
  width: min-content;
}

.comment-box .image img{
  width:24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment-box textarea{
  height: 50px;
  width: 1 ;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
          <div class="list">
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/ok.webp"></div>
              <div class="user-name">
                <div class="name">TOM</div>
                <div class="day">100 days ago</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="comment">LOREM IPSUN DABUN VUB</div>
          </div>
          <div id="new-comment">  </div>

          <div class="comment-box">
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/OK.webp"></div>
              <form>
              <textarea name="comment" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" id="comment-box"></textarea>
              <button id="post">Comment</button>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Look into the <template> element

Comment: You can have comment markup within your template element and then clone it with JavaScript

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y17RuWkWdn8

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Basically you need to passing a node when using appendChild() method.

Create a div node,

```
// create an element node
// var text = document.createTextNode(userComment);
var text = document.createElement('div');
text.innerText = userComment;
```

And pass it to the new comment section,

```
// note: you need to pass a node to appendChild() method
// newComment.appendChild(userComment);
newComment.appendChild(text);
```

Hope it helps!

```js
var post= document.getElementById("post");
post.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('coment button pressed');

    var userComment = document.getElementById("comment-box").value;
    console.log(userComment)

    // create an element node
    // var text = document.createTextNode(userComment);
    var text = document.createElement('div');
    text.innerText = userComment;
    console.log(text)

    var newComment = document.getElementById("new-comment");
    console.log(newComment)

    // note: you need to pass a node to appendChild() method
    // newComment.appendChild(userComment);
    newComment.appendChild(text);
})
```

```css
.comment-box,
.post-comment .list{
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
}

.comment-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-comment .list{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.post-comment .list .user{
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-comment .list .user img{
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.comment-section .name{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-comment .list .day{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post-comment{
  padding: 0 0 15px 58px
}




#comment-box{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.comment-box .user{
  display: flex;
  width: min-content;
}

.comment-box .image img{
  width:24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment-box textarea{
  height: 50px;
  width: 1 ;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="user">
        <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/ok.webp"></div>
        <div class="user-name">
          <div class="name">TOM</div>
          <div class="day">100 days ago</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">LOREM IPSUN DABUN VUB</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="new-comment"></div>

    <div class="comment-box">
      <div class="user">
        <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/OK.webp"></div>
        <form>
        <textarea name="comment" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" id="comment-box"></textarea>
        <button id="post">Comment</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `newComment.appendChild(userComment)` by `newComment.appendChild(text);` And here you are, I added some small updates like clearing the text area after sending a comment, and adding the comment into a paragraph to prevent showing different sent comments in the same line:

```js
var post= document.getElementById("post");
post.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var userComment=document.getElementById("comment-box").value;
    
    var text= document.createElement('p');;
    text.innerHTML = userComment;

    var newComment = document.getElementById("new-comment");

    newComment.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById("comment-box").value = "";
   
})
```

```css
  .comment-box,
  .post-comment .list{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
  }

.comment-section{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post-comment .list{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.post-comment .list .user{
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-comment .list .user img{
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.comment-section .name{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post-comment .list .day{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.post-comment{
  padding: 0 0 15px 58px
}




#comment-box{
  border:none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.comment-box .user{
  display: flex;
  width: min-content;
}

.comment-box .image img{
  width:24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.comment-box textarea{
  height: 50px;
  width: 1 ;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-comment">
          <div class="list">
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/ok.webp"></div>
              <div class="user-name">
                <div class="name">TOM</div>
                <div class="day">100 days ago</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="comment">LOREM IPSUN DABUN VUB</div>
          </div>
          <div id="new-comment"></div>

          <div class="comment-box">
            <div class="user">
              <div class="user-image"><img src="./images/OK.webp"></div>
              <form>
              <textarea name="comment" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" id="comment-box"></textarea>
              <button id="post">Comment</button>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```